# Display data in table in laravel with table

Tags: php, css, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, crosstab

I have fetch data from database in laravel but now I want to display data like following image

```
public function crossTabDegreesPdf($degree){

        $degAdmin_department = Auth('degAdmin')->user()->department_id;        
        $examcode  =  ExamCodeTb::where('is_active',1)->pluck('examcode');
        $examcode  =  $examcode[0]; 

       $student_records=DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT student_tbs.regno,student_tbs.stdName,student_tbs.stdfName,student_tbs.department_id,student_tbs.degree_id,college_tbs.name FROM student_tbs INNER JOIN  college_tbs ON  college_tbs.college_id = student_tbs.department_id WHERE  department_id = $degAdmin_department AND degree_id = $degree");

        $all_records = array();            
        foreach ($student_records as $record){
                  $regno = $record->regno;
                  department_id = $record->department_id;

        $student_rollnos = DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT roll_no_tbs.regno,roll_no_tbs.rollno,roll_no_com_dets.subcode,roll_no_com_dets.obt40,subject_tbs.Na,subject_tbs.semester_id,subject_tbs.hours,dbo_web_part.P_name,dbo_web_part.OneRTwo FROM  roll_no_tbs INNER JOIN roll_no_com_dets ON roll_no_com_dets.rollno = roll_no_tbs.rollno LEFT JOIN subject_tbs ON subject_tbs.code   = roll_no_com_dets.subcode LEFT JOIN dbo_web_part ON  dbo_web_part.part = roll_no_tbs.part where roll_no_tbs.regno= $regno ORDER BY  roll_no_com_dets.rollno");
$all_records[] = array('students'=>$record,'rollnos'=>$student_rollnos);

        }
return view('front.degadmins.degrees-pdf')->with('all_records' ,$all_records);
}
```

In my view want to display data something like the upload image

[image]

Comment: no image found.

Comment: Please see the first answer i have forget to upload image

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: Sir i want to display data like the image attached i am not able to display data like this image

Comment: please Upload atn image of your output and code in view file.

Comment: <?php
   dd($all_records);
   $semester;
   $college;
   $degree;


   foreach ($all_records as $record) {

    $college  =  $record['students']->name;
      foreach ($record['rollnos'] as $rollno){
        $semester = $rollno->OneRTwo;
        $degree = $rollno->P_name;
      
      }
   }


  ?>

Comment: You can edit your question. with code you have written in blade file to show table